# Adding a function to a dom element using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, prototype

I am trying to add a custom function to a specific div elements in my dom that share the same class name.

Something like this

```
$(".custom-div").each(function(){
        $(this).newFtn = function() {
            $(this).addClass("makeover");
        }
});
```

So here am trying to add the newFtn to the div elements with the class name ".custom-div".

After trial and error and inspecting of the element in firebug. I got this to work the following way

```
$(".custom-div").each(function(){
        $(this).init.prototype.newFtn = function() {
            $(this).addClass("makeover");
        }
});
```

But, I have a few question on this; I am not sure of why this works and are there any draw backs of doing it in this manner? Can someone explain this please ? An abstract explanation should be fine.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You're not adding functions to a DOM element, just the JavaScript object representing them.  What you are attempting makes no sense to me.  Why not just add the class directly?

Comment: @Brad : Sorry if my question wasnt specific enough to my needs.. i was just trying to keep it simple.. Here is a summary of what i am trying to achieve "I am trying to create a custom checkbox using a div.. So I want to provide a function named "disable()" so that when called this check box gets disabled(changing the css and also changing an attribute name)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
function DisableCheckBox(o) {
    //No need for $('selector') here as 'o' is a jQuery object already.
    o.each(function () {
        o.addClass('makeover');
    //Other stuff...
    });
    //optionally return o on function exit if you want to do stuff to it outside this function
}

DisableCheckBox($(".custom-div"));
//or
var chk = DisableCheckBox($(".custom-div")); //if returning 'o' above.
```

Answer (score 9):

I think what you want to do is write a jQuery plugin. The basic idea is this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.newFtn = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            //Do stuff for each element in matched set
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can then apply this method to any jQuery object:

```
$(".custom-div").newFtn();
```

Note that this is the way most of the built-in jQuery methods work (they iterate over the matched set of elements themselves, so there's often no need to use `each`).

You can learn far more about jQuery plugin development by starting with the [official tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

If you really want to simply add a class to all of the elements in the matched set, there is absolutely no need to do any of this. Simply call `addClass` on the jQuery object. It will apply to all elements contained within that object.

Comment: `this.each(function() {` should actually be `return this.each(function() {` (assuming you want to maintain chainability :) )

Comment: @pete - Very true. I have linked to the plugin tutorial so I'll leave it up to the OP to figure the rest out!

Comment: I am aware of adding custom functions so that they can be applied to any jQuery object.. I am trying to create a custom checkbox using a div.. So I want to provide a function named "disable()" so that when called this check box gets disabled(changing the css and also changing an attribute name).. Since this is very specific i felt i should not add it as a function to any jQuery object.. Am still a beginner so will take your suggestions on how to go forward..